# append to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, append

My problem is this,

i need to try to create a dictionary that will hold the count values of each cluster from a dataset i am using.

I want my programme to use a while loop to enter keys into the dictionary based on an integer from user input.

here is some code

```
numberofclusters = raw_input("Enter the number of clusters")

clusters = {}
while numberofclusters >= 0:
```

so if the user entered 3 the dictionary should look like this

```
{ cluster1: 0, cluster2: 0, cluster3: 0
```

}

how would i get the current number from the `numberofclusters` variable? so that i can append `"cluster[x]"` to the dictionary?

Comment: Note that the keys need to be strings, 'cluster1', etc.

Comment: @Andrew the keys do not need to be strings, they need to be *hashable objects* (which includes things other than strings).

Comment: @Rafe, yes, I didn't mean to imply that. But in this case I think the questioner means strings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you'll want to re-think your loop logic. As it stands now, your while loop will continue infinitely -- numberOfClusters will always be greater than 0 (unless the user enters a negative value or 0 as input).

You should consider using a for loop, instead:

```
for i in range(0,numberOfClusters):
    # loop logic
```

This will iterate from 0 up to numberOfClusters, and you'll have access to which iteration you are on by reading the variable "i".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> num_of_clusters = int(raw_input('Number: '))
Number: 3
>>> clusters = {}
>>> for i in range(1, num_of_clusters+1):
        clusters['cluster{0}'.format(i)] = 0

>>> clusters
{'cluster2': 0, 'cluster3': 0, 'cluster1': 0}
```